# Пустые поля в БД

Tags: mysql

В общем есть таблица с  полями id(первич ключ), pass, login, type, one и two.

Когда регаются у не которых получается type - type_1, а у других других type_2, ну и у одного типа(type_1) поля: one и two  не заполняются.

Лучше из этой таблице создать  две таблице? Или оставить такую

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вопроса. А как увелечение количества таблиц решает проблема пустых полей?

Да и не смотря на то что не совсем понял вопроса - думаю что - тупо забить :)

Comment: уже исправил

Comment: Я догадываюсь это вы таки образом подразумеваете что-то типа групп пользователей.

Если это так то лучше всего сделать для каждого пользователея поле, например - **group** и хранить в нем id таблицы групп( ее естественно тоже для этого нужно создать )

А уже в таблице групп описывайте все что вам необходимо, таким образом у вас в БД не будет каши...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если только я правильно понял, Вас смущает наличие пустых полей в таблице. 
Можно создать отдельную таблицу-потомка с полями id(внешний ключ), one, two. В этом случае null-полей не будет, но немного усложнятся запросы.

Answer (score 1):

Что-ж если вы задаете подобный вопрос - поздравляю, вы достигли следующего уровня :-)

Теперь вам нужно изучть вопросы

- нормализацией данных
- де-нормализацией тех-же данных
- использование модели Entity–Attribute–Value
- и что-бы все это быстро работало :-)

И использовать полученные знания при проектировании базы данных